# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Using asp.net webforms I receive this error on line 1:

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'

```
<h2 id="Title" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">Evaluations</h2>
```

Comment: I'd love an explanation for the down votes. I ran into this problem and searched stack overflow and there is not an existing question on this already. The answer is not intuitive and I thought It was worth sharing for people in the future to find.

Comment: I'd guess the lack of code is the reason.

Comment: @juharr Should I really have posted an entire .aspx page for the question? That seems like a lot of noise when the code is clear in the answer. 

I could put the one line that the problem is occurring on into the question, but at the time of my problem at least I had no idea where the problem was. The error indicates line 1 but it is not on line one.

Comment: No, but at least the line the problem occurs on. Or if that's not the actual problem, then a minimal set of code that reproduces the problem.  And just because you have it in the answer doesn't mean it shouldn't be in the question.  Think about if you didn't have the answer, then no one would have known.

Comment: But if I didn't have the answer, I would have no idea what line the problem is occurring on?

Comment: That's when trying to reproduce the error with a minimum set of code is advised to both help you figure it out and to give anyone looking at the question something to work with.

Comment: I guess i'll put it in there, I was trying to come from the perspective of someone doing a google search for the answer who also has no idea of the problem line, and I didn't want them to see code in the question that doesn't immediately seem like theirs and move on without seeing the answer. I can't believe this question is even getting close votes for being *off topic* now. This is clearly a programming question. It's easy to see why so many feel so discouraged when trying to contribute to this site.

Comment: @Kyle Even a self-answered question is supposed to meet all guidelines for asking a good question. Sometimes (often) more answers show up. It would be hard for readers to pick out the one that supplies the missing pieces.

Comment: I was trying to be the most helpful possible rather than check guideline boxes. Including the single line of code seems potentially more confusing, but I have gone ahead and done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `ID="Title"` with `runat="server"`.

Changing the ID to anything else, like Title1 or PageTitle, and the page compiles and runs fine again.

```
<h2 id="Title" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">Evaluations</h2>
```

To:

```
<h2 id="PageTitle" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">Evaluations</h2>
```

Fixes the problem.

This problem is caused because the partial class that gets generated hides the existing Title on the control.